# Notepad++ Regex Issue

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a regular expression which I tested here (https://regex101.com/) and it works there. 
In the following string:

```
https#58//sites.google.com/site/sasispellingprimer/primer/MK_my_mother_2.m4a
```

I want to capture only 'primer' and replace it with 'test.' 
There are other URLs in my document that have the word 'primer,' so I need to capture the file extension to make sure I'm changing the correct URLs. I only want to change URLs pointing to an audio file.

Here is my regex (which does not return any results in Notepad++ but does work on the regex101 site):

```
(?:\/sasispellingprimer\/(primer)\/.*\.m4a)
```

Comment: [Works for me](https://i.imgur.com/Eq8l3gF.png)..

Comment: silly just checking...do you have the regular expression selected in the search mode.?

Comment: Yes I do, and it's not returning any results for me. Not sure why.

Comment: [This](https://i.imgur.com/s3nLGSt.png) is how I successfully replaced `primer` with `test` in your string using Notepad++. Note that I changed your expression a bit. The search expression is `/sasispellingprimer/primer/(.*)\.m4a` and the replacement is `/sasispellingprimer/test/\1.m4a`. Try that, and make sure your dialog matches mine, I guess.

Comment: It works! Can you explain why please? (I can never get the hang of regex.)

Comment: The search expression is just the text "/sasispellingprimer/primer/", followed by a captured group (the brackets) containing *something* (`.` == any character, `*` == repeat any number of times), followed by ".m4a" (escaping the `.` with `\.` so it means a literal `.`, not "any character". The only thing in the replacement expression that's not literal text is `\1`, which means "the thing that was captured in the first capturing group".

Answer (score 0):

You just need this regex: `\bprimer\b(?=.*.m4a)` which is also working in Notpad++

Meaning of regex : find the primer word which having ending with extendtion m4a

[Demo and Explaination](https://regex101.com/r/aE2aR7/4)